# How to set null for looping value when serialize

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4, json.net

I could not find a title for my  question.
I have class as below

```
class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Employee> Subordinates { get; set; }
}
```

if i serialize this class object, it is look like as below

```
[
  {
    "Name": "first person",
    "Subordinates": [
      {
        "Name": "second person",
        "Subordinates": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Name": "second person",
    "Subordinates": null
  }
]
```

But i need it like this

```
[
  {
    "Name": "first person",
    "Subordinates": null
  },
  {
    "Name": "second person",
    "Subordinates": null
  }
]
```

How can i get this
I am not using only this class. I have many class like employee so i need one solution for my all classes.
I am using below code for one class. I know it's not a solution, but i didn't find any better solution

```
var employees = //sql query .ToList()
foreach(var item in employees){
    item.Subordinates = null;
}
```

`return Json(employess)`

Comment: you can modulate `var employees = //sql query .ToList()` , for that provide sql query or Linq query

Comment: The thing is that "first person" seems to have a subordinate "second person". Why don´t you just solve that?

Comment: NicoRiff: The problem is that a naive deserialization of the output as it it is will result in two different instances for `"second person"`, which is not desired. It is desired that the hierarchical references of the instances is respected.

Comment: @Viplock
I am using LINQ. LazyLoading is enable in my dbcontext

Comment: yes provide the code of linq , your solution can be derived from there

Comment: @Viplock Can you give an example?
For example. i use such as `var employess = db.employees.ToList()`

Comment: let me add a formal answer for you, update me if you fave any issue.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem.  Is it 1) Flattening the employment hierarchy to a list, or 2) Serializing a list of objects where one specific property has to get mapped to `null`?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what serializer you are using, the solution differs.

Try adding `[NonSerialized]` `[XmlIgnore]` `[ScriptIgnore]` to the `List` property.

Comment: Thank you. Yes it is a solution but i dont want this. Because i  will use this depth in future. I'm thinking create a WebApi so if i use that, i need many request for one json

Comment: Then you can use the attribute and when you'll want the webapi, remove it

Comment: I think i can use it for a while. Thank you :)